# Three images side by side, responsive without scaling

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design

I cannot find the exact answer to my question, so hopefully someone can help me.

I have three images. I want them side by side on a large screen.
On a smaller screen (tablet) I want two of them to be in rows.

And on small phone screen I want them all to be in rows above each other, centered.

The code that I have so far is:

```
<div align="center">
<div style="width: 371px; float: left;"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/magenthemes2/images/review1.png"}}" alt="" width="371" height="270" /></div>
<div style="width: 371px; float: left;"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/magenthemes2/images/review2.png"}}" alt="" width="371" height="139" /></div>
<div style="width: 371px; float: left;"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/magenthemes2/images/review3.png"}}" alt="" width="371" height="139" /></div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work right. It is also not centered. I'd like it to render like this:

**Responsive example on different screen sizes**

[image]

Comment: Ues `@media` queries or simply use Bootstrap framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of float you can also work with the text-align attribute. In the following example you can see how I used it for boxes on a front-page. They automatically adjust to different screen-sizes (click on "Run code snippet" and then on "Full page").

```css
.entries-box {
  /* Style for box containing Frontpage boxes */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
.entry {
  /* Style for a Frontpage box */
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.4em 0.8em 0.4em 0.8em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 1em 0.4em 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #007f59;
}
```

```html
<div class="entries-box">
  <div class="entry newest-e">
    <b>Title of Storie</b> - Genre (Lang icon)
    <br>'Excerpt of newest entry, max. 2 lines
    <br>Second line of excerpt...'
    <br>_User_
  </div>

  <div class="entry newest-e">
    <b>Title of Storie</b> - Genre (Lang icon)
    <br>'Excerpt of newest entry, max. 2 lines
    <br>Second line of excerpt...'
    <br>_User_
  </div>

  <div class="entry newest-e">
    <b>Title of Storie</b> - Genre (Lang icon)
    <br>'Excerpt of newest entry, max. 2 lines
    <br>Second line of excerpt...'
    <br>_User_
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you both. It succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to give the parent `<div>` a class name, and then apply different styles to it in different `@media` queries. More can be read about `@media` [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). you could use [this site](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/), or [this site](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints) for a simpler but less complete overview, as a cheatsheet for which media queries you could use.

An example of some code that would work for a selection of devices is:

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  .imagebox > img {
    float:left;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  .imagebox > img:first-child {
    float:left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div align="center" class="imagebox">
  <div style="width: 371px; float: left;"><img src="https://placekitten.com/250/300" alt="" width="371" height="270" /></div>
  <div style="width: 371px; float: left;"><img src="https://placekitten.com/250/150" alt="" width="371" height="139" /></div>
  <div style="width: 371px; float: left;"><img src="https://placekitten.com/250/150" alt="" width="371" height="139" /></div>
</div>
```